# How to Get Attribute Value of XMLHttpRequest in Results

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, crm

I have the following `Microsoft Dynamics` related `XMLHttpRequest` javascript function, and is encountering issue when attemtping to retrieve the entity attributes of the returned records.

The record managed to be created even though the conditions should have blocked it. It is likely that my following statement caused the issue:

`var result1 = results.results[0];`

`alert("result1: " + result1.id); //Not displayed`

```
function DisableInvalidRecordCreation(context) {

    var saveEvent = context.getEventArgs();
    var idNumber= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("IDNumber").getValue();
    var category= Xrm.Page.getAttribute("Category").getValue();
    var id = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();

    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/ccc_cases?$select=IDNumber&$filter=IDNumber eq '" + idNumber+ "' and statecode eq 0", false);
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("OData-Version", "4.0");
    req.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
    req.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
    req.setRequestHeader("Prefer", "odata.include-annotations=\"*\",odata.maxpagesize=1");
    req.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (this.readyState === 4) {
            req.onreadystatechange = null;
            if (this.status === 200) {
                var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
                if (results.value.length > 0 && id == "") {
                    alert(results.value.length); //Displayed as 1
                    var result1 = results.results[0];
                    alert("result1: " + result1.id); //Not displayed
                    for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
                        var returned_category= results.entities[i]["Category"];
                        alert(returned_category); //Not displayed
                        if (category == 100000003 && returned_category!= 100000003)
                        {
                            alert("Invalid record");
                            saveEvent.preventDefault();
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
            }
        }
    };
    req.send();
}
```

Comment: Why not just use the retrieveRecord method? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/model-driven-apps/clientapi/reference/xrm-webapi/retrieverecord

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because in your get request you are selecting only IDNumber field and not the one you desire like `Category`

```
 req.open("GET", Xrm.Page.context.getClientUrl() + "/api/data/v9.0/ccc_cases?$select=IDNumber&$filter=IDNumber eq '" + idNumber+ "' and statecode eq 0", false);
```

Also it should not be `var result1 = results.results[0];`
rather it should be  `var result1 =results.value[0]`

sample code snippet for reference

```
if (this.readyState === 4) {
        req.onreadystatechange = null;
        if (this.status === 200) {
            var results = JSON.parse(this.response);
            for (var i = 0; i < results.value.length; i++) {
                var abc = results.value[i]["abc"];
                var xyz = results.value[i]["xyz"];
                var pqr = results.value[i]["pqr"];
                var pqr_formatted = results.value[i]["pqr@OData.Community.Display.V1.FormattedValue"];
            }
        } else {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(this.statusText);
        }
         }
```